# a problem with applying automatic weights

Tags: rigging, vertex-weights

i have been following a rigging tutorial on you tube and then i encountered a problem with parenting the armature to my character 
i right clicked the character mesh then the armature and i pressed ctrl+p and then chose the automatic weights option
the error was : bone heat weighting failed to find a solution for on for two bones
i have read several answers on the forums and here is what i have tried
1.removing doubles
2.selecting all the bones without .l and .r extensions and then s->x->0

and here is the .blend file https://github.com/phantomcoder1996/blendermodels/blob/master/man.blend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a subsurf modifier to the mesh as shown below:

[image]

Then parent the mesh with the armature again and it will work as shown below:

[image]

Updated .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: thanks .you have saved me a lot of time ,but why is the subdivision surface modifier required??